# How to fix this error?

Tags: errors

[*** MWE ADDED AT BOTTOM ***]

I need help understanding the error I am getting on the line with only }. They are marked below...While it doesn't affect anything when I compile it,  I would like to fix it, because any changes I make cause it to not be able to compile. LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. Any help would be great.

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{1ex}{\tikz \draw[->, line width=1.25mm] (0,0)--++(1,0);}}

\newcommand{\ocgItem}[2]{%
\colorbox{%
\ifcase#1 \or
red\or
green\fi
}{\huge Item 1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg1}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}  
\\
\\
\\
  {\Huge Project 1} \\ 
\\
\\
\\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
    \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
             \colorbox{white}{%
                \parbox{10cm}{%
                    \colorbox{green}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.18cm}} 
  Step 1
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}\\%
                    \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Step 2
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}\\%
                    }%
                 } %ERROR ON THIS LINE
    \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[***EDIT***]  MWE below

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}    
\colorbox{red}{% 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c} 
  Step 2
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
} %ERROR ON THIS LINE
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `tikz` needed here as [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) seems to be sufficient for `\resizebox`? Also, `\myarrow` is never used, is it, nor is the requirement that you have to set this in `landscape` mode? Please consider reading this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\colorbox` is an horizontal box. Neither environment `center` nor command `\centering` do have any business there. The uneven left and right margins comes from the additional unwanted space from the line end after `\end{tabular}`. Fixed example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    Step 2
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Centering the `\colorbox` inside the `\parbox` is best done with `\centering` *outside* `\colorbox`:

```
\parbox{10cm}{%
  \centering
  \colorbox{green}{...}%
}
```

Comment: You're right....

Answer (score 3):

Replace `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` with `\centering` and all is well.  The code below compiles fine.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}




\begin{document}    
\colorbox{red}{% 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c} 
  Step 2
\end{tabular}
} %NO ERROR ON THIS LINE
\end{document}
```