# How to Adjust Sizes in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, ocg

I hope this is a minimum example, I don't know how to make it any smaller without getting rid off what I need help with... Anyway, there are 4 total boxes or "Projects" and they all have to show up on the one beamer slide. They were all showing up previously on landscape, but that was before I put it into beamer and now they are not all fitting on to the page (and I made it wider by using 16:9 ratio also). I tried to make the boxes smaller, but when I did that, there was no space in between the boxes and they overlapped. Basically I just need the 4 boxes across the screen evenly and  not overlapping/running off the screen. Sorry I'm still pretty new to this...any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.90in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-2.90in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4in}

\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{1ex}{\tikz \draw[->, line width=1.25mm] (0,0)--++(1,0);}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\small
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg1}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \\
    \\
  {\Huge Project 1} \\ 
  \\
  \\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
        \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
                \colorbox{white}{%
                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                        \colorbox{green}{
\begin{tabular}{m{4.18cm}} 
  Item 1
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 2
\end{tabular}
}}\\%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 3
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 4
\end{tabular}
}}\\%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 5
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 6
\end{tabular}
}%
                        }%
                    }
        \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\indent \myarrow
\indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg2}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \\
    \\
  {\Huge Project 2} \\ 
  \\
  \\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
        \begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
                \colorbox{white}{%
                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 1
\end{tabular}
}}\\%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 2 
\end{tabular}
}%
                        }%
                    }
        \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\indent \myarrow
\indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg3}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \\
    \\
  {\Huge Project 3}\\
   \\
   \\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
        \begin{ocg}{OCG 3}{ocg3}{0}
                \colorbox{white}{%
                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 1
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 2
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 3
\end{tabular}
}}\\%
                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 4
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 5
\end{tabular}
}}%
                        }%
                    }
        \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\indent \myarrow
\indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\switchocg{ocg4}{%
\fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
    \bfseries\Large%
    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    \\
    \\
  {\Huge Project 4}\\
  \\
  \\
\end{tabular}}}}\\%
        \begin{ocg}{OCG 4}{ocg4}{0}
                \colorbox{white}{%
                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}}
  Item 1
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 2 
\end{tabular}
}\\%
                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}
\begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
  Item 3
\end{tabular}
}}%
                        }%

       \end{ocg}
\end{minipage}%
\end{frame}

%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe removing the `center` environments would be a good starting point? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318958/how-to-fix-this-error

Comment: @samcarter sorry, thought I had done it already in this version, that's fixed now, no more center environments...I did notice something removing the center environments though. The red boxes appear slightly wider than the green boxes, do you know how to fix this? Also, any help with the original question would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For the different sizes of the red and green boxes: compare the width of the `tabular`s inside the boxes.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks that worked!...anything on the other issue?

Comment: @samcarter Sorry to bother you again, but just one final problem/question hopefully...I can't figure out how to get the arrows to be completely out of the boxes. With what there is now the left side of the arrow is still in the left box (of the two boxes the arrow connects), is there a way to fix it so the arrow is in between the two boxes?

Comment: Quick and dirty: put some space in front of your arrow `~~\myarrow`

Comment: @samcarter Awesome, thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! But please never again ignore latex errors, just because the unpredictable result happens to look like what you think it should look like.

Comment: @samcarter Yeah. I understand. It was much easier working with it and making changes after getting rid of the errors

Comment: Successful day: one soul saved from damnation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove your modifications of the margins, you can comfortable fit your diagram to the page by adding a `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}` around your content. Alternatively you can use the shrink option, e.g. `\begin{frame}[shrink=40]` or whatever value fits your needs.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}


\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{1ex}{\tikz \draw[->, line width=1.25mm] (0,0)--++(1,0);}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        %\small
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
            \switchocg{ocg1}{%
                \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
                    \bfseries\Large%
                    \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
                            \\
                            \\
                            {\Huge Project 1} \\ 
                            \\
                            \\
                        \end{tabular}}}}\\%
                        \begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
                            \colorbox{white}{%
                                \parbox{10cm}{%
                                    \colorbox{green}{
                                        \begin{tabular}{m{4.18cm}} 
                                            Item 1
                                        \end{tabular}
                                    }\\%
                                    \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
                                            \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                Item 2
                                            \end{tabular}
                                        }}\\%
                                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                            \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                Item 3
                                            \end{tabular}
                                        }\\%
                                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                    Item 4
                                                \end{tabular}
                                            }}\\%
                                            \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                    Item 5
                                                \end{tabular}
                                            }\\%
                                            \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                    Item 6
                                                \end{tabular}
                                            }%
                                        }%
                                    }
                                \end{ocg}
                            \end{minipage}%
                            \indent \myarrow
                            \indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
                                \switchocg{ocg2}{%
                                    \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
                                        \bfseries\Large%
                                        \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
                                                \\
                                                \\
                                                {\Huge Project 2} \\ 
                                                \\
                                                \\
                                            \end{tabular}}}}\\%
                                            \begin{ocg}{OCG 2}{ocg2}{0}
                                                \colorbox{white}{%
                                                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                                                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                    Item 1
                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                            }}\\%
                                                            \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                    Item 2 
                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                            }%
                                                        }%
                                                    }
                                                \end{ocg}
                                            \end{minipage}%
                                            \indent \myarrow
                                            \indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
                                                \switchocg{ocg3}{%
                                                    \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
                                                        \bfseries\Large%
                                                        \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
                                                                \\
                                                                \\
                                                                {\Huge Project 3}\\
                                                                \\
                                                                \\
                                                            \end{tabular}}}}\\%
                                                            \begin{ocg}{OCG 3}{ocg3}{0}
                                                                \colorbox{white}{%
                                                                    \parbox{10cm}{%
                                                                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                                                            \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                Item 1
                                                                            \end{tabular}
                                                                        }\\%
                                                                        \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                                                            \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                Item 2
                                                                            \end{tabular}
                                                                        }\\%
                                                                        \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
                                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                    Item 3
                                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                                            }}\\%
                                                                            \colorbox{green}{\normalsize 
                                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                    Item 4
                                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                                            }\\%
                                                                            \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}{
                                                                                    \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                        Item 5
                                                                                    \end{tabular}
                                                                                }}%
                                                                            }%
                                                                        }
                                                                    \end{ocg}
                                                                \end{minipage}%
                                                                \indent \myarrow
                                                                \indent \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
                                                                    \switchocg{ocg4}{%
                                                                        \fcolorbox{black}{white}{%
                                                                            \bfseries\Large%
                                                                            \resizebox{5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
                                                                                    \\
                                                                                    \\
                                                                                    {\Huge Project 4}\\
                                                                                    \\
                                                                                    \\
                                                                                \end{tabular}}}}\\%
                                                                                \begin{ocg}{OCG 4}{ocg4}{0}
                                                                                    \colorbox{white}{%
                                                                                        \parbox{10cm}{%
                                                                                            \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}
                                                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}}
                                                                                                    Item 1
                                                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                                                            }\\%
                                                                                            \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}
                                                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                                    Item 2 
                                                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                                                            }\\%
                                                                                            \colorbox{red}{\normalsize \color{white}
                                                                                                \begin{tabular}{m{4.3cm}} 
                                                                                                    Item 3
                                                                                                \end{tabular}
                                                                                            }}%
                                                                                        }%

                                                                                    \end{ocg}
                                                                                \end{minipage}%
                                                                            }
                                                                            \end{frame}
                                                                            %
                                                                        \end{document}
```

[image]